# playgameservices/android-basic-samples tutorial for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've been trying to set up the basic samples in Android Studio for awhile now with no luck.  This is what I've tried so far; I've downloaded the samples as a zip and then extracted it in my Android Studio Projects folder.  Next I open Android Studio and select File->New->Import Project and then select the Basic Sample Folder (Note: there is no Select "Import from existing model - Gradle" as the [ReadMe file instructs](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples)).  I get an error telling me that it can not find the [build tools version](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/218) , so I just hard coded in the build tools version like so:

```
if (!project.hasProperty('android_version')) {
    ext.build_tools_version = "23.0.2"
}else{
    ext.build_tools_version = project.getProperty('android_version')
}
```

next I was getting an error telling me the min version couldn't be below 15 and so I went through the gradle files and changed the min version from 9 to 15.  After this it asks me to upgrade my Gradle Plugin.

> To take advantage of all the latest features (such as Instant Run),
>   improvements and security fixes, we strongly recommend that you update
>   the Android Gradle plugin to version 2.2.0 and Gradle to version
>   2.14.1.

If I don't upgrade the program it compiles but when I run it I get this error:

> 10:44:33 AM UnsupportedMethodException
>               Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getPluginGeneration().
>               The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
>               To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
>               Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.

If I do update the Gradle Plugin I get these two errors, failed to crunch file:

> Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to
>   crunch file
>   C:\Users\Me\AndroidStudioProjects\android-basic-samples-master\BasicSamples\libraries\BaseGameUtils\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.2.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png
>   into
>   C:\Users\Me\AndroidStudioProjects\android-basic-samples-master\BasicSamples\libraries\BaseGameUtils\build\intermediates\res\merged\androidTest\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':libraries:BaseGameUtils:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources'.
>
> > Error: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file
> >     C:\Users\Me\AndroidStudioProjects\android-basic-samples-master\BasicSamples\libraries\BaseGameUtils\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.2.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png
> >     into
> >     C:\Users\Me\AndroidStudioProjects\android-basic-samples-master\BasicSamples\libraries\BaseGameUtils\build\intermediates\res\merged\androidTest\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png

So that's about as far as I've gone, I'm really only interested in running the SkeletonTbmp application, so maybe it would be more straightforward to try and set up each project individually.  If anyone can see where I'm going astray I'd appreciate any help / advice offered.

Edit: For those interested here's my Android Studio build, also see the comments in the accepted answer for the solution.

[image: Version]]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably opening the incorrect folder. Make sure that the folder you are importing in Android Studio is the entire `android-basic-samples` folder:

[image]

After you import, synchronize gradle and then configure the sample you're trying to run as an Android module.

If that doesn't work, try building the samples from the command-line in the `android-basic-samples` folder:

```
cd android-basic-samples/BasicSamples
./gradlew assemble
find . -iname *.apk
...
```

You may also want to try changing line 44 of `BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/build.gradle` to:

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

Change the minimum SDK version in `BasicSamples/build.gradle` to:

```
android_min_sdk_version = 15
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to Import the project again with the same result.  When I run from command line I get

* What went wrong:           
A problem occurred evaluating project ':libraries:BaseGameUtils'.
> Could not find property 'build_tools_version' on com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension_Decorated@58c93be3.

Comment: In the build.gradle file for BaseGamesUtils, try changing 

buildToolsVersion build_tools_version to buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

Comment: Ok I finally got it to install, in BasicSamples.gradle file I add this line to the ext block build_tools_version = android_version (or your comment works too) and change android_min_sdk_version = 15, then I opened the Project Settings and selected Build Execution Deployment and disabled instant run. Then I synchronize project with the gradle files and choose not to upgrade the gradle plugin, after it builds I can then run it on my phone.